# How to Auto validation textbox value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, time

I have textbox in diaolog box , ID = txtTime in file .aspx and I have file .js

I want to compare input from user on txtTime and current time.
if txtTime <= current time then show something(alert or anything) that say to user it false.

first, How do I call txtTime value on .js file ?

second, I need to convert from string to time in file .js because my dialog code in .js (I use jQuery UI for dialog)

So, How do I convert from string to time with javascript ?
this is my textbox element detail.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="txtTime" />
```

above is my code on .aspx. the value is like (I use Time picker jQuery)

> 10:15 PM

if need information about my time picker, I use [jQuery time picker from here](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) option number 2

Comment: There's about a hundred timepickers for jQuery, most of them has built in methods for returning a date object ?

Comment: why not <input type="time" /> ??

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string you can use something like this:

```
var pikedTime = "12:50";
var timeArray = pikedTime.split(":");
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(timeArray[0]);
now.setMinutes(timeArray[1]);
//now is the current date with piked time (12:50)
```

`now` is `Date object` : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

So, to implement in your code you can use `onSelect` callback:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    onSelect : function(timePiked){
       var now = new Date(),
           datePiked = new Date();
        if(timePiked.match(":") !== null){
            timePiked = timePiked.split(":");
            datePiked.setMinutes(timePiked[1]);
            datePiked.setHours(timePiked[0])
            console.log(datePiked > now); //if true piked date is higher than current date
            // datePiked is the time you have piked from input
            // "now" is the current time (calculated every time you change data inside form)
        }
    }
});
```

---

An alternative is to set `minTime` for prevent the selection of time lower than curret:

```
var now = new Date();
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    minTime : {
        hour: now.getHours(),
        minute : now.getMinutes()
    }
});
```

---

Watch the documentation: https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/ on tab 2 ("usage").

1. property `onSelect`
2. property `minTime`

(minTime is the example number **14**)

Comment: my code is like this '$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#timepicker_7').timepicker({
            showPeriod: true,
            showLeadingZero: true
        });
    });'

so I need to add minTime on this script ?